# Unable to load script. Make sure you`re either running a Metro server

Tags: javascript, react-native, facebook

Estou criando meu primeiro projeto com o simulador Genymotion.
Consigo criar o projeto normalmente digitando no terminal:

```
react-native init
```

depois de criado, entro no meu projeto:

```
cd myproject
```

Agora ao rodar o android para enviar para o simulador surge o problema. Bem, ao rodar no terminal:

```
react-native run-android
```

ele envia para o simulador, porém aparece o seguinte erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Digitei no terminal o comando

```
react-native start
```

e percebi que está dando erro...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Recomendo você utilizar o AVD(Android Virtual Device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema acontece porque no linux(pelo ao menos no meu também não) o empacotador não é iniciado automaticamente.

O que você deve fazer é abrir uma nova aba no terminal no mesmo caminho do projeto e rodar `npm start`.

Com essa aba rodando basta executar em outra janela: `react-native run-android`.